# D3.js d3.max undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

this is my first question and I´m completely new to the wonderful d3.js.
I try to make a choropleth map out of a geojson file with 12 objects and a lot of properties.

I want to calculate the domain for the colorscale (quantize) by d3.min and d3.max, but something must be wrong. The values of min and max are still undefined(if I believe my webinspektor).
With Numbers in the domain tags all works fine.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks for every answer.

Here is my code:

```
d3.json("IKSK_LK_Goe_31463.json", function (collection) {




                overlay.afterAdd = function () {                    // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.


                    color.domain([
                            //1,30
                            d3.min(collection, function(d) {return d.features.properties.EINWOHNER;}),
                            d3.max(collection, function(d) {return d.features.properties.EINWOHNER;})
                            ]); 
                            console.log(d3.max(collection, function(d) {return d.features.properties.EINWOHNER;}));
```

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? You should inspect "collection" and see how it is structured. You are likely not using min/max correctly. You want to pass in an array of objects and then "d" represents each of the elements in the array. So, if your properties are on the elements of the "features" array which is in "collection", you would call "d3.min(collection.features, function(d){return d.properties.EINWOHNER;})"

Comment: Thank you,your answer was as fast as correct. You made my day (after 3 days of headache over that:-)

Comment: Also useful to note is the d3.extent() function which returns the min and max of your data as an array so can be fed directly to the domain. You use it in the same way you would min and max, it just replaces the need to use both.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, the input to d3.max should be an array.
Make sure the input is not object, if it is make an array of the values using d3.values(collection);

```
var collection = {
  '01': { foo: 'bar', value: 10 },
  '02': { foo: 'baz', value: 20 }
};

var collection_array = d3.values(collection);
// --> [{ foo: 'bar', value: 10 }, { foo: 'baz', value: 20 }]
d3.max(collection_array, function (d) { return d.value});
// --> 20
```

Best of luck!

/Wille

Answer (score 2):

If `d.features.properties.EINWOHNER` is an integer value, or you want to extract the integer value from it (that's how min and max make sense) then add a `'+'` before it, like this:

```
    d3.min(collection, function(d) {return +d.features.properties.EINWOHNER;}),
    d3.max(collection, function(d) {return +d.features.properties.EINWOHNER;})]);
```

Answer (score 1):

adding + in front of your numeric variable might help, as mentioned by others.

A great and simpler d3 function to get min/max and use it as a domain is

## d3.extent(array[, accessor])

Returns the minimum and maximum value in the given array using natural order. This is equivalent to calling d3.min and d3.max simultaneously.

so color.domain(d3.extent(...)) will set the domain properly, as well.

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
var xx = [{x:'one',y:1}, {x:'two',y:2}]; //array
var maxOfY = d3.max(xx, function(d){ return d.y;});
```